# shell script to find file extension

Tags: git, shell

I'm working on a shell script that i'm using in git that checks if this is the file extension then execute this executable file, else do this. I have written this but not working

```
if [[ $~x1  == *.datalink ]] then
C:/Users/salees/Compare.exe $1 $2
else
C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
exit 0
```

Anyone know how to work around with this?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the error?

Comment: What particular shell are you scripting?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using window 7. I selected a datalink file and its not calling my Compare.exe file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=file.datalink
extension=${x##*.}

if [[ $extension = "datalink" ]] then
    # do something
else
    # do otherwise
fi
```

assuming you put the file name in the `x` variable, "file.datalink" in the example

Comment: `[[ ]]` is nothing but a portability pitfall and the equality operator should be `=` (not the nonstandard `==` disease).

Comment: the file name is unknown yet. the file name shouldn't be predefined as i may select any kind of file to compare in git. Thanks